# The next.js component returns an empty object when accessing the getStaticProps and getServerSideProps props

Tags: next.js, getserversideprops, getstaticprops, static-compilation

I have a simple Nex.js project using version 14.0.4. I am using MUI CSS to style following the documented setup: https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/nextjs/.

I have a layout.jsx file in root with the following configuration:

```
 `// layout.tsx
     import { AppRouterCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v14-appRouter';
     export default function RootLayout(props) {
       const { children } = props;
       return (
         <html lang="en">
            <body>
               <AppRouterCacheProvider>{children}</AppRouterCacheProvider>
            </body>
         </html>
      );
    }`
```

And inside the pages directory I have _app.js and _document.js:

```
 `//pages/_app.js
    import '../styles/globals.css'
    import { AppCacheProvider } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v14-pagesRouter'
    import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles'

    import Home from '.'
    import theme from '../components/theme'

    function MyApp(pageProps) {
      return (
        <AppCacheProvider {...pageProps}>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Home/>
          </ThemeProvider>
       </AppCacheProvider>
     )
}`

export default MyApp
```

//_document.js
import { DocumentHeadTags, documentGetInitialProps } from '@mui/material-nextjs/v14-pagesRouter';
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
export default function MyDocument(props) {
return (


<DocumentHeadTags {...props} />






);
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = documentGetInitialProps;

In my index.js I am trying to access the props object from my component with an array that I obtain when processing the content of some files in my project directory. Everything is correct and I'm sure that getStaticProps saves my data array in the props, but I still get an undefined value if I access it from the component:

```
import fs from 'fs/promises';
import Image from 'next/image'
import Link from 'next/link'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import Header from '../components/Header'

export default function Home({latestComics}) {
   console.log(latestComics)
   return (
     <>
     <Header/>
     <div className={styles.container}>
       <main className={styles.main}>
         <div>
         {latestComics && latestComics.length > 0 ? (
               latestComics.map((comic) => (
                 <Image key={comic.title} src={comic.img} alt={comic.title} />
               ))
           ) : (
             <p>No comics available</p>
           )}
         </div>
       </main>

       <footer className={styles.footer}>
         <a
           href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
           target="_blank"
           rel="noopener noreferrer"
         >
           Powered by{' '}
           <span className={styles.logo}>
             <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
           </span>
         </a>
       </footer>
     </div>
     </>
   )
}

export async function getStaticProps(){
   let comics = await fs.readdir('./comics')
   comics = comics.slice(-8);
   const promisesReadFiles = comics.map(async(file) =>{
     const comicFile = await fs.readFile(`./comics/${file}`, 'utf-8');
     return JSON.parse(comicFile);
   })

   const latestComics = await Promise.all(promisesReadFiles).catch(error => {
     console.error(error);
     throwerror; // Throws the exception to indicate that there is a problem.
   });
   console.log(latestComics)

   return{
     props: {
       latestComics
     }
   }
}
```

I have tried deleting the .next folder from my project and building again with `*npm run build*` expecting to receive some kind of alert in the console, but it compiles successfully without any errors. I run the project again and continue to receive my `latestComics` prop as: undefined. Does AppCacheProvider or AppRouterCacheProvider have anything to do with this?